# Proteger un archivo php que muestra json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo mi archivo PHP:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('hostejemplo.com','usuario','contraseña') or die('no se puede conectar');
mysql_select_db('basededatos');

$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla";
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($arr);
echo $json;
?>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que no cualquiera pueda ver esos resultados? Tal vez con un simple login de nombre de usuario pero ¿cómo quedaría?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una pregunta demasiado amplia, pero si este script solo se va a utilizar dentro de algunos sistemas y no corres riesgo de que alguien haga un abuso del mismo podrias validar usando un hash fijo agregando el siguiente codigo al principio del script

```
if ($_GET["token"] != "840a552b8269b09a49569b71ff10a07d"){
    die("Access denied");
}
```

De esta forma si al ejecutar el script no se le envia el parametro correcto solo mostrara "Access denied".